# Why Deepl can't exclude jpg images while translating html text?

Tags: java, json, gson, deepl

I use Deepl for translating HTML text. If I have a `.gif` file in my HTML it is okay but if I use `.jpg` I get the following error. I know `Deepl` uses `gson` in his lib but don't know how to solve it, I am wondering if any Deepl guys know about this issue?
I use Deepl java lib.

**Any solution welcome in advance?**

**Error location in the code:**

```
        boolean failed = false;
        String translationResult = "";
        try
        {
            TextResult result = translator.translateText( text, source, target, translationOptions );
            translationResult = result.getText( );
        }
        catch (IllegalStateException | JsonSyntaxException exception)
        {
          failed = true;
          //...
          exception.printStackTrace( );
          Show.error( "failded"+ exception.getMessage( ) +"\n"+ exception.getCause( ) );
        }
        
        if(failed) {
            Show.error( "failded" );
        }
```

**Error**

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
13/10/2022 10:22:45,483 [AWT-EventQueue-0] ERROR [JBroker] User Message: faildedjava.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:225)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:991)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:956)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:905)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:876)
    at com.deepl.api.parsing.Parser.parseErrorMessage(Parser.java:47)
    at com.deepl.api.Translator.checkResponse(Translator.java:769)
    at com.deepl.api.Translator.translateText(Translator.java:174)
    at com.deepl.api.Translator.translateText(Translator.java:110)
    at com.upsilon.screens.translator.DeeplTranslator.translate(DeeplTranslator.java:75)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Daniel Jones mentioned it is a bug that Deepl going to fix it.

To work around this until the definitive Deepl solution, I did the following.

1. Extracted all `<img src ="" />` tags from `HTML text` and put them into a hash map with a  dynamically created `<ignoreImage> image1</ignoreImage>` tags as key and the original `<img src ="" />` tags as value `Map<String,String> imageTagMap = new HashMap();`
2. Replaced all `<img />` tags with `<ignoreImage>image1</ignoreImage>` tags in my `HTML text`
3. Translated the text and after getting translation result replaced the `<ignoreImage>image1</ignoreImage>` tags with the original tags according to my `imageTagMap` .

I think this solution can also be used in Deepl java lib to avoid unnecessary image transport over the network to their server.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a maintainer of the DeepL Java client library.

This problem seems to be caused by a bug in the Java client: the HTTP response is assumed to be valid JSON and this exception is thrown because the response was not valid. I'll work on a fix to the client, and update when it's released.

Edit 19.10.2022: A bug causing JsonSyntaxException to be thrown is fixed in v0.2.1, however the underlying issue is still unknown.

Comment: Thanks for the rapid reply. Is it also possible to add a feature such as `Translator.isAuthKeyValid("key");`  to the class Translator?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer before: the Java client throws a JsonSyntaxException due to a bug; this bug is fixed in version 0.2.1. With that bug fixed the error response should be more helpful.

However I am not sure why your input HTML was rejected in the first place, and I wasn't able to reproduce it yet. Can you share a minimal example input that triggers the error?